# Climate checking my map

Tags: planets, environment, climate, worldbuilding-process

[image]
So I've decided to come here to see how my map would be effected by climate.
Notes: The planet has a 10° axial tilt, it's a little smaller then earth, and has earth like conditions.
So my questions are:

1. I've heard the tilt of a planet affects the tropics and polar circles, in pretty sure they are placed in the correct locations. Would this placement affect the size of the temperate band on this planet making it the biggest?
2. The ocean currents of this planet would affect the land how? And are there any noteworthy effects the currents would have on the land?(Optional)
3. With all these answered how would biomes be placed on this map? (Optional)

If there is any other questions about it feel free to comment and I'll get to them as soon as I can!

Comment: Your map _sortof_ reminds me of Earth before the Drake (s.america) and Tasman(australia) passages opened. So this means your ocean currents will be fairly isolated from one another as well as well mixed. Ie no very cold circumpolar current. This will allow warmer temperatures to reach higher latitudes than what we see today. Not writing a full answer as I think the question is currently too broad. I wrote an answer on [Eocene weather](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/120903/what-was-the-weather-like-in-the-eocene/121009#121009) you may be interested in.

Comment: So based off what that link says n the planet would be warmer due too large warm ocean currents not getting affected by the landmasses. And with lower tilt compared too earth the planet would be more temperate and wet. And the polar regions would be warmer as well with little permanent ice coverage. Is that what you are getting at @EveryBitHelps

Comment: Sortof. Climate is very complicated and interlinked. It's why we struggle so much getting a straight answer The Eocene also had a different atmospheric composition. There was alot more dust/aerosols/carbon dioxide etc in the air creating a very large greenhouse affect. This helped with the warming. So if you have a thinner atmosphere  (or less co2) etc you could negate some of the warmth if you are wanting a cooler planet. You can also adjust the temperature/distance to the sun etc. You could also crash a landmass or two if you want a 'temporary' cold snap. Say for eg india and asia...

Comment: Yea, climate is SOOO confusing, but your explanation is "simple" in terms of saying "the planet is like this due to ocean currents". I like it! I don't want to explain how the planet the planet got like this due too some wierd astronomical circumstance. So thank you! I'll more research on it. @EveryBitHelps

Comment: this is a very broad question, you may want to break it up into multiple parts. I Will tell you the western half of your largest continent will be nothing but desert.

Comment: So do you want me to segment the map? @John

Comment: I was saying you need to ask individual questions not put everything in one, 1, 2, &3 should be individual questions. Sectioning the map will not help, it may actually make it harder, although overlaying a large grid would make discussing it easier.

Comment: Mmmmmm, I'll try to do that I guess, I can make the questions later

Answer (score 1):

1) Assuming that you have axial tilt of 10 degrees, then you're getting:

- higher temperature difference between poles and equator
- very mild temperature difference between seasons (unless planet orbit is quite eccentric)

No, temperate band would be presumably smaller.

2) This question depends on direction of rotation of your planet, please specify that. (Possibly also specify length of day, for somewhere around 18h-48h you should get Earhlike 3 Hadley cells)

3) Deponens on second question. What I see right now:

- biome with temperate climate with no real winter and vegetation during whole year (axial tilt)
- no savanna dependent on rain season (axial tilt)
- huge desert on the main continent (huge landmass + mountains blocking all rain clouds)

Answer (score 0):

The biome placement depends on things like how far your planet is from your star, how long the star has been there, etc.

Also, with less gravity than Earth the mountains would be taller and the oceans would be deeper.

Also, how long has your planet been there? Multicellular life has been around for half a billion years. There would be less seasonal difference with the axial tilt of your planet.

Comment: I would say the distance from the host star would be earth-like, also I would say the size difference between this planet would be small, and be able to produce earth-like gravity. Honestly these are factors I haven't thought about do I'll end my comment here but I'll fill you in later when I have an answer.